# Android Fragment Active on Opening

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using `ViewPager`. I have 3 fragments (A,B,C) and two of them(A & C) are populating `ListView` from the server, so it will take a few seconds for that. And I am showing a `ProgressDialog`. B is the fragment which is set to show first and its is not having any background process, having a few buttons only.

So the problem is that the `ProgressDialog` will always show upon creating that activity,that is all the Fragments are loaded always.

So I wonder if I can load the specific `Fragment` only (A or C) when I open it (Slide) so that the user who want to use the Icon menu (B fragment) should not need to wait for the other fragments (A & C) to load. I am not sure whether its possible or not. Can anyone suggest me any code snippets or references to achieve it. Any help regarding this will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I had done it easily with `AsyncTask` and the `Fragments` are updated in background